# "QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called" appears when using QMediaPlayer

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtmultimedia

I implemented widget for playing media files like this:

[.h file](https://github.com/DevAlone/Flamingo/blob/master/src/views/lesson/content_view/mediaplayerwidget.h)

[.cpp file](https://github.com/DevAlone/Flamingo/blob/master/src/views/lesson/content_view/mediaplayerwidget.cpp)

If you want to compile it in your environment, you should copy also this files: [mediaslider.h](https://github.com/DevAlone/Flamingo/blob/master/src/views/lesson/content_view/mediaslider.h) [mediaslider.cpp](https://github.com/DevAlone/Flamingo/blob/master/src/views/lesson/content_view/mediaslider.cpp) and add multimedia and multimediawidgets on your .pro file

It just uses QMediaPlayer and QVideoWidget like in the examples in Qt documentation.

I create widget like this:

```
MediaPlayerWidget player;

player.setSource(
"path_to_videofile");

player.show();
```

Everything works fine, but when I am resizing the window, it appears next text in console:

> QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called

What's going on? I didn't call QWidget::paintEngine. Is it Qt bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a Qt bug.  QWidget::paintEngine is [for Qt core internal use only](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEngine) but QMediaPlayer seems to be using it, possibly indirectly via a WA_PaintOnScreen flag being set at some point inside the library.

For what it's worth, [you are not the only person to notice this issue](https://community.nxp.com/thread/435213), and if the player works the warning can be ignored fairly safely.  Future Qt updates will likely resolve this issue over time.